# dynamic method invocation in expression tree

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, expression-trees, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

When constructing an expression tree, I have to use nodes invoking external methods in order to obtain values the expression could then continue evaluation with. 
These methods are supplied as `Func<T>` and my code has no knowledge of where they originate from.

What is the most correct way of performing the mentioned invocation? I've tried something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Delegate> _externalSymbols;

private Expression _forExternalSymbol(string identifier)
{
    Delegate method = _externalSymbols[identifier];
    return Expression.Call(method.Method);
}
```

which works as long as the `method` fetched from the dictionary was created in compile-time. However, in case of `Func<T>` being a dynamic method obtained, for instance, by compiling another expression in runtime, this won't work out throwing

> ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Int32 lambda_method(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExecutionScope)'

The desired effect may be achieved by wrapping the given function into one extra expression, but that seems quite hideous comparing to what it used to look like:

```
private Expression _forExternalSymbol(string identifier)
{
    Delegate method = _externalSymbols[identifier];
    Expression mediator = method is Func<double> ?
        (Expression)(Expression<Func<double>>)(() => ((Func<double>)method)()) :
        (Expression<Func<string>>)(() => ((Func<string>)method)());
    return Expression.Invoke(mediator);
}
```

Also, this is hardly an extensible approach should I need to add support for types other than `double` and `string`.

I would like to know if there are better options which would work with dynamically created methods (preferably applicable to .NET 3.5).

Comment: What about arguments? Do these methods take any arguments, or not?

Comment: @nightwatch No arguments, dictionary is guaranteed to contain only `Func<T>` delegates with T being either `double` or `string` (the list of these types may well require extension in future).

Comment: I don't know linq expressions that well, sorry. But what you're doing looks like a dynamic invocation with method names being resolved at runtime. Maybe you could just use a dynamic object as an interface to your external functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which works as long as the `method` fetched from the dictionary was created in compile-time

No, it works as long as the `method` is static. For example, it also won't work if the delegate is a lambda that references something from its parent score (i.e. it's a closure).

The correct way to invoke a delegate is to use [`Expression.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170). To get an `Expression` that represents your delegate, use `Expression.Constant()`:

```
Expression.Invoke(Expression.Constant(method)))
```

Comment: Well, actually it works for non-static methods (in this case an overloaded version must be used with `Expression.Constant(method.Target)` as the 1st argument, by bad). The problem is, the dynamic methods do not have a `Target`. Your answer is just what I needed, thanks!